# Test cross browser in the same test case using protractor

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, cross-browser

I need to test a chat app and the way i want to test is open one instance of chrome and another instance of firefox and send messages between both. From what I found I can open two browser sessions but they are for the same application and use multi-capabilities for testing all the test cases cross-platform. Has anyone attempted this?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
So I added this to my protractor configuration i have tried with to test the same test case on multiple browsers

```
  multicapabilities:[
    {
       browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    {
       browserName: 'firefox'
    }
  ]
```

I added this and I was able to run the same test case on multiple browsers independently.

Since I needed a test case run on multiple browsers. I found that we could use browser.forkNewDriverInstance(). This allowed me to launch multiple windows of the same browsers. This enabled me test more scenarios. And now I need to be able to test mutiple browsers(firefox, chrome) in the same test case.

Please let me know if any more information needs to be provided.

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you've tried. It is important to post code examples and give more information so that someone might be able to look at and help you fix what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching more stackoverflow pages and github issues. I found this article https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4962. That tells me how to start chrome and firefox together in the same test case. and the code i used is below:

```
describe('Video Tests', () => {
    let ffBrowser: ProtractorBrowser;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        ffBrowser = await protractor.browser.forkNewDriverInstance().ready;
        (await ffBrowser.getProcessedConfig()).capabilities = {
          'browserName': 'firefox',
          'marionette': true,
          'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            'prefs': {
              'media.navigator.streams.fake': true,
              'media.navigator.permission.disabled': true
            }
          }
        } // new caps goes here;
        ffBrowser = await ffBrowser.restart();
    });

    it('testing cross browser', async () => {
      await browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
      await ffBrowser.get(browser.baseUrl);
      await browser.sleep(5000);
    });

    afterEach(async () => {
      // Assert that there are no errors emitted from the browser
      const logs = await browser.manage().logs().get(logging.Type.BROWSER);
      expect(logs).not.toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
        level: logging.Level.SEVERE
      } as logging.Entry));
    });
  });
```